# Why is it an error in Dart to try to set a static variable in the global namespace?

Tags: dart

Why is it an error in Dart to try to set a class's static variable in the global space?

Example:

```dart
class Name {
  static String? firstName;
}

Name.firstName = 'Mike'; // Error

void main() {
  Name.firstName = 'Mike'; // Ok
}
```

It's not a big deal. I just came across this and then couldn't find an explanation for why it is.  Where in the documentation does it describe the nuance here?

[UPDATE]

The actual error thrown is, among others: "Variables must be declared using the keywords 'const', 'final', 'var', or a type name."

You actually can execute statements outside of a function, but they have to be statements that declare scoped variables.  Maybe these aren't technically statements, but just variable instantiations.

```
class Name {
  static String? staticName;
  String? lastName;
}

final me = Name(); // Ok
me.lastName = 'Jones'; // Error

void main() {
  Name.staticName = 'Mike'; // Ok
  final you = Name(); // Ok
  you.lastName = 'Smith'; // Ok
}
```

Without the variable scoping, the compiler thinks I must be defining a function and it gets confused when there is no parameter list or function body.

It makes sense that statements are restricted to variable instantiations of function definitions only, so that there won't be side effects related to execution order to other importers of the file, as per @jamesdlin answer.

Comment: You're using it neither in a class or a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Name.firstName = 'Mike';` is a statement.  You can't execute arbitrary statements in the global namespace.  In what order would they execute?  Suppose you had:

`name.dart`:

```dart
class Name {
  static String? firstName;
}
```

and `mike.dart`:

```dart
import 'name.dart';
Name.firstName = 'Mike';
```

and `spike.dart`:

```dart
import 'name.dart';
Name.firstName = 'Spike';
```

and finally:

```dart
import 'name.dart';
import 'mike.dart';
import 'spike.dart';

void main() {
  print(Name.firstName);
}
```

What should happen?  Should it be illegal for multiple libraries to assign to `Name.firstName`?  Should the last one `import`ed win?  If so, then suddenly importing a library would have *side-effects*, and order would matter.  What would happen if an imported library imports other libraries with side-effects?

It's a huge headache that is completely unnecessary since you could have just done:

```dart
class Name {
  static String? firstName = 'Mike';
}
```

in the first place.